# How to get the image links from Gutenberg block gallery and add them as html data attributes to a button in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using gutenberg gallery block inside a post and I'm trying to create a button which contains all of the image ids in the gallery block as html data attributes such that later when I output the content to the page I can have access to those ids using `javascript`. Basically I'm trying to create a lightbox feature for a custom post type.

The problem is that I can't get access to the gutenberg gallery block data.

Here's my code

```php
while ($custom_post_type->have_posts()) {
    $custom_post_type->the_post();
    $gallery = get_post_gallery(get_the_id(), false);
    $ids = explode(",", $gallery['ids']);
}
```

And here's that button with html data attributes

```html
<button class="gallery" 
<?php 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
  $img_link = wp_get_attachment_image_url($ids[$i], 'full');
  echo "data-img-" . $i . " = " . $img_link . " ";
}?>
>
Light-box
</button>
```

But it does not work, `$ids` is empty. It prints out this

```html
<button class="gallery">Light-box</button>
```

Thanks for your help!

#### Edit

I'm using wordpress blocks on the post page, I'm not quite certain how they have been generated, but they work out of the box.

[image]

Comment: It really depends on how you've created your gutenberg block. Could you explain more on how you've created your block?

Comment: Hi @Ruvee thanks for your response, please see the edited section of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"it does not work, `$ids` is empty."*

That block is one of the default wordpress blocks, aka "core blocks". In order to have access to its data you would need to use `parse_blocks` function not `get_post_gallery`. That's why your variable is empty.

---

So the overall workflow to get what you're looking for would be:

1. Check whether your post has any blocks or not, using `has_block` function. [`has_block`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_block/)
2. If it does, then get all of the blocks (including gallery block) using `parse_blocks` function. [`parse_blocks`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/)
3. `parse_blocks` will return an array of all blocks used in your post, so loop through them and see which one is called `"core/gallery"`.
4. `"core/gallery"` block has `"attributes"` and `"ids"` for each image you've added in the admin panel.
5. Once you get the `"ids"`, you should be able to create your custom button and image links using `wp_get_attachment_image_url` function. [`wp_get_attachment_image_url`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/)

---

As a POC:

[image]

Please see the following code:

```php
if (has_block("gallery", get_the_content())) 
{
  $post_blocks = parse_blocks(get_the_content());
  foreach ($post_blocks as $post_block) 
  {
    if ("core/gallery" == $post_block["blockName"]) 
    {
      $ids = $post_block["attrs"]["ids"];
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the button:

```html
<button class="gallery" 
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
  $img_link = wp_get_attachment_image_url($ids[$i], "full");
  echo "data-img-" . $i . " = " . $img_link . " ";
}
?>
>
Light Box 
</button>
```

Which will return:

[image]

**Note:**

- I've used `get_the_content` function, assuming that you're in the loop based on the code you provided in your question. If you're not in the loop or you would need to use the code outside of the loop you could use `global $post; $post->post_content;` instead.

---

This answer has been tested on wordpress `5.8` and works.

Comment: Saved me from holidays frustrations, thx a lot.